# Existence of a generalized matrix inverse over an arbitrary field?

Tags: linear-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, matrices

Let $A\in M_n(K)$ be a square matrix over a field $K$. The notion of inverse matrix was generalized by Moore and Penrose for real and complex matrices
(also called pseudo-inverse $A^{\dagger}$ of $A$, satisfying 
$AA^{\dagger}A=A, A^{\dagger}AA^{\dagger}=A^{\dagger}$ and $AA^{\dagger}$  Hermitian). This was again generalized to arbitrary fields with involutory automorphism of $K$ by Pearl, but the existence depends on additional rank conditions.

**Question:** What is known on the existence of a *generalized inverse* $A'$, which just satisfies $AA'A=A$, over an arbitrary field ? 
Do we also need an additional assumption, perhaps on the characteristic of $K$, or again some rank condition ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The condition $AA'A=A$ means that the semigroup of matrices is regular. This is really true: see Clifford - Preston, The Algebraic Theory of Semigroups, sec.2.2, ex. 6(g).

Comment: Thank you, Boris. Do you have some other reference where this is proved ? (I have no access to the book).

Comment: @ Dietrich Burde: Have you access to Semigroups and Combinatorial Applications by Gérard Lallement? If yes, then see in it Proposition 4.2.

Comment: Yes, thank you. And the proof is really not difficult.

Comment: @ Dietrich Burde: OK. Good luck!

Comment: Adding on to @BorisNovikov's answer: Proposition 4.2 in Chapter 2 (p. 39). (There are also Proposition 4.2s in Chapters 6 and 8.)